# Copy hierarchy of SCSS class / id in PhpStorm or Webstorm

Tags: sass, phpstorm, webstorm

Given a hierarchy like this:

```
.layer-1{
    .layer-2{
        a{
            &.on{}
        }
    }
 }
```

I just want to copy the whole hierarchy of `a.on` to reuse it for media queries.

Is there a way of doing this without copying the already defined rules? It seems as PhpStorm is able to SHOW the hierarchy but I just want to copy it.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more "real world" example: a code with some rules in it and what you should get in the end? If question is: can I get the same structure stripped of all possible rules -- then answer will be No (I'm not aware of such functionality).

Comment: Still waiting for option to copy class breadcrumbs :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
.layer-1{
    .layer-2{
        a{
            &.on{
                $mySelector: & !global;
            }
        }
    }
 }

 @media (x:y) {
     #{$mySelector} {
          // your styles
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't copy hierarchy. Write `@media` inside.

```
.layer-1{
    .layer-2{
        a{
            &.on{
                @media { ... }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```